# Angular CLI ng build - undefined:8:53494: property missing ':'

Tags: angular-cli

Angular CLI build fails with below:

```
ng build
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
√ Copying assets complete.
× Index html generation failed.
undefined:8:53494: property missing ':'
```

I found this is because of my CSS file linked in angular.json

```
"styles": [ "src/assets/css/cui-standard.min.css"]
```

I tried to disable inlineCritical but with no luck:

```
"optimization": {
              "scripts": true,
              "fonts": { "inline": true },
              "styles": { "minify": true, "inlineCritical": false }
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it's complaining about something on line 8 column 53494 of that `cui-standard.min.css` minified CSS file. Might be kind of hard to troubleshoot without seeing that file. Can you maybe post a snippet of that file, starting a little bit before the referenced column number (and let us know the position you copied from)? Or maybe try included the non-minified version instead (if available) - it will probably also error out, but hopefully be a bit easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I used the stylesheet in the <head> instead and it works now:

<link href="https://www.cisco.com/web/fw/cisco-ui/2.0.5/dist/css/cui-standard.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

For some reason it was failing to build when included with the application.

Comment: hi Rado if you using the inline external fonds like google fonts the internet required for build time also make inline critical to true for more detils https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration